# Which UITextFiled did change?

Tags: swift, xcode

There are 2 UITextFiled, username and password.

Using the function:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {  
    }
```

I can detect if there is a change, but how can I know if this change is in the Username UITextFiled? or is it in the Password UITextFiled?

Comment: You have a var myPassWordTextField: UITextfield and same for the username, no? then if textField == myPassWordTextField {}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lame !
first create UITextFields:

```
let username = UITextField()
let password = UITextField()
```

then

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField, reason: UITextField.DidEndEditingReason) {
    var ColName = ""
    if textField  == username { print("username value is entered") }
    if textField  == password { print("password value is entered") }
}
```